# Limit of $n!^{1/n^2}$ using Squeeze Theorem?

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find the limit of $n!^{1/n^2}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

What I've done so far is:

I know that $n < n^2 < n! < n^n$ for large $n$,

and I know that $n^{1/n^2} = 1$, but I'm not sure how to find the limit of $n^{n^{1/n^2}}$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $n^{1/n^2}\to 1$, not $=1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $n!^{1/n^2} \le (n^n)^{1/n^2}=n^{1/n}.$

Answer (score 0):

One more way: $t=e^{log t}$ and then compare the sum over $ \log n$ to the integral. The limit is 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $(n!)^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}≤(n^{n})^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}$ since $n!≤n^{n}$, the above implies that
$$(n!)^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}≤(n^{n})^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}=n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

As in turn $1≤n!$, then

$$1≤(n!)^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}≤n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

And as $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (1) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n^{\frac{1}{n}}) = 1$ then by Squeeze Theorem

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (n!)^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}=1$$